# Geometric interpretation of $x^3+y^3+z^3=k^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, pythagorean-triples

$a^2+b^2=c^2$ is related to right triangles - how the sums of the squares of the legs equals the square of the hypotenuse.

What about the following sum of cubes?
$$x^3+y^3+z^3=k^3$$
Is there a geometric interpretation for this, like there is with the Pythagorean theorem?  Is there some shape that embodies this equation, like a right triangle does for $a^2+b^2=c^2$?  Would it involve sums of volumes of certain cubes?

Comment: At the most apparent level, this is the formula for the plot of a three-dimensional sphere of radius $k$. The solutions are the points on the sphere.

Comment: @dsillman2000:  no, that would have all the variables squared, not cubed.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot+x%5E3%2By%5E3%2Bz%5E3%3D1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer it's a sphere, but not with the usual Euclidian metric, but instead is the $L^3$ metric in a 3D space. In the Euclidian or $L^2$ metric, in $n$ dimensions, the norm is given by $$||X||_2=(x_1^2+x_2^2+...)^{1/2}$$ In general, the distance in the $L^p$ metric is given by the above equation by replacing $2$ with $p$
$$||X||_p=(x_1^p+x_2^p+...)^{1/p}$$ 
You can find more details on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space) or there is a nice [movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ineO1tIyPfM) on youtube (the shape of $L^3$ circle is shown at 6 minutes and 17 seconds in this clip).