# What is the volume of the solid defined by $x^4+y^4+z^4=1$ enclosed in a box of unit length?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, volume, quartics

I came across a post on [the geometric interpretation of $x^3+y^3+z^3 = t^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2305117/geometric-interpretation-of-x3y3z3-k3) asking if it was a higher analogue of the Pythagorean theorem.

It made me wonder: if we plot $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, of course we get a sphere. But if [we plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%20x%5E4%2By%5E4%2Bz%5E4%3D1) $x^4+y^4+z^4=1$, we get this solid instead:

$\hskip1.8in$[image]

I know by a result of Elkies that this has infinitely many rational points $x,y,z$. What else is known about this solid?

1. For one, what is its name?
2. Also, if we snugly enclose it in a box of unit length, what is its volume?

---

**P.S.** For [the case](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%20x%5E5%2By%5E5%2Bz%5E5%3D1) $x^5+y^5+z^5 = 1$

$\hskip1.8in$[image]

Comment: The question in your title is different from the two questions you ask in the body... (Also: probably you shoud explain what it means for a box to have unit length (unit side?) and why doesn't the volume of the (cubic?) box is not determined by the side!)

Comment: Question 2 confuses me a little. This solid has a well-defined volume, regardless of whether or not "we snugly enclose it in a box of unit length". Did you mean to ask something different, or is the unit length box a red herring?

Comment: You may call these bodies "N-dimensional ball in p-norm". (Here: N=3, p=4). Their general volumes are given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301506/

Comment: @Andreas: Ah, should have known this would be well-studied.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: Turns out it is a duplicate. Should I delete it?

Comment: This shape is also a *superellipsoid* and a *superquadric*.

Comment: @Andreas: Can you look at [this plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot+x%5E5%2By%5E5%2Bz%5E5%3D1) for $x^5+y^5+z^5 = 1$? It looks more like a sheet than a ball. Is there something wrong with WolframAlpha's rendering?

Comment: You want $|x|^5+|y|^5+|z|^5 = 1 $ for proper balls. Without the absolute values, you get "sheets" due to negative signs in other than the first orthant.

Comment: @LeeMosher: It didn't seem to have a "radius", and it had sloping corners so how to measure its length? So the nearest thing that I could think of was to constrain it in a box of unit length.

Comment: @Andreas: That makes sense.