# Geometric quantity related to $a^3 + b^3 + c^3$

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

The following geometric proof of the Pythagoras theorem

[image]

relies on the fact that one can cut out 4 right angled triangles (of area $\frac12ab$ each) out of a square of side length $a+b$ to obtain another square. That is, $(a+b)^2-4\times\frac12ab$ is a square of a quantity, and it is easy to see that this quantity is the hypotenuse of the right-angled triangle of perpendicular sides $a$ and $b$.

In a similar vein, since $(a+b+c)^3 = a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + 3(a^2b+ab^2+a^2c+ac^2+b^2c+bc^2) + 6abc$, is it possible to cut out finitely many tetrahedrons, whose total volume adds up to $3(a^2b+ab^2+a^2c+ac^2+b^2c+bc^2) + 6abc$, out of a cube of edge-length $a+b+c$ and be left with a perfect cube with the volume of $a^3+b^3+c^3$?

In case it is possible, does this edge of length $(a^3+b^3+c^3)^{1/3}$ have a nice geometric interpretation?

Edit 1: The edge-lengths of each such tetrahedron should lie in $\mathbb{Q}[a,b,c]$, otherwise it is trivially possible.

Comment: By using edges from $\mathbb{Q}[a,b,c]$ and spatial diagonals between their ends, you only get **quadratic** irrationalities. Ever heard of [doubling the cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_the_cube)?

Comment: Thanks @IvanNeretin that makes sense. So I believe the construction I am asking about is not possible?

Comment: So it seems.$\,$

Comment: Build 8 tetrahedrons "around" the vertices. What is left, 1/3abc, in the middle is cut into tetrahedrons.

Comment: @Moti I didn't quite understand your construction, but are you implying that the construction posed in the above question is possible?

Comment: Cutting a cube into tetrahedron is easy. The construct of tetrahedrons in the sum, is also straightforward (which I assume you know how). I see the challenge and I am not sure you could get the cube as desired.

Comment: A [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2305117/geometric-interpretation-of-x3y3z3-k3) back in 2017 regarding the quantity $a^3+b^3+c^3$.

Comment: Thank you @TitoPiezasIII